# Same code giving different results in Online IDE and local IDE

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, garbage

Below program is used to remove the duplicates from a sorted singly linked list. The code gives garbage values in online IDE. But when I comment the  line .

```
delete curr;
```

The program works fine in online IDE itself.  Here is the function I wrote. The other parts of the code are well-defined(not by me) by the online Judge.

And also the code without commenting the line **delete curr;** works fine in local IDE(codeblocks).

**FULL PROGRAM:**http://ideone.com/9bHab0

Why do I get the garbage values?

```
Node *removeDuplicates(Node *root)
{
 // your code goes here
    struct Node* curr = root,*prev = NULL;
    while(curr)
    {
        if(prev==NULL)
            prev = curr;
        else if(curr->data!=prev->data)
            prev = curr;
        else
        {
            prev->next = curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr = prev->next;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

**EDIT:** One could see the pointer whose location is deleted, is reassigned immediately. Thus there couldn't be a dangling pointer here!

Comment: Did you try running it under a debugger?

Comment: You *do* allocate your `Node` instances with `new`? *All* of them? What are their destructors doing?

Comment: That's a happy mixture of C (`struct Node* curr`) and C++ (`delete curr`) code. Are you sure, that the caller is C++, and calls `operator new` to allocate instances?

Comment: that will go into an infinite loop as soon as it has to go through the else if block - are you sure this is your actual code

Comment: But it actually passes all test cases of online Judge, when I comment the particular line **delete curr**.

Comment: @IInspectable - the full code link shows the allocation is done via new. using `struct` is perfectly normal in C++

Comment: @JinxerAlbatross So? That doesn't mean it's good. It means you hid undefined behaviour by replacing it with a memory leak.

Comment: @TomTanner: I don't look at off-site resources. Questions on SO are supposed to be self-contained. This is explained in the instructions on how to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take a very simple example, with a two-node list, where you have e.g.

```
node1 -> node2
```

With the first iteration then `prev` is `NULL` so you do `prev = curr`. Now `curr` and `prev` points to the same node.

That means in the second iteration both `if` conditions are false (`prev != NULL` and `curr->data == prev->data`) you go into the `else` part, where you have

```
prev->next = curr->next;
delete curr;
curr = prev->next;
```

Here you `delete curr` ***but*** `curr` is pointing to the same memory as `prev`, leading to *undefined behavior*  in the assignment `curr = prev->next`, as you now dereference the stray pointer `prev`.

To make matters worse, you then enter a *third* iteration where `prev` is still pointing to the deleted first node, and again dereference the invalid `prev` pointer (in your second `if` condition) and you once again end up in the `else` part where you continue the invalid dereferencing. And so on in infinity (or you get a crash).

Comment: And the solution is: Replace `prev = curr;` with `prev = curr; curr = curr->next;` in the first two conditional branches.

Comment: Adding **curr = curr->next** to the **if part and else if  part** solved the problem. Thanks for the solution. Should I change the header of the question to avoid unwanted attention  towards this question?